# Empty <Div> is added when using async router in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I'm using this library https://github.com/SimpleContacts/react-router-async-routes

My route:

```
<Route
            async
            path="/app"
            render={() =>
              Axios.get('/api/loggedin')
                .then(data => <MainApp />)
                .catch(err => <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: this.props.location } }} />)
            }
          />
```

An empty div is added:

[image]

If I do this:

```
  <Route path={`${match.url}app`} component={MainApp} />
```

No div is added.

Is it possible to get rid of this empty `Div`? Alternativly, how do I add a class to this `div`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, I believe that your div is coming from the [library](https://github.com/SimpleContacts/react-router-async-routes/blob/master/src/Route.js) you are using (line 77). One of your choices is to make a pull request to that library and replace the `div` with what might be helpful to you, or to make a fork to the repo and refactor it without the `div`

Comment: Thats crazy. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help, feel free to mark it as answered if you are satisfied with my response.

Comment: Yes. I wait for a while. Maybe someone comes up with a better solution :)